# Making scalable columns with Materialize

Tags: css, materialize

I have this form that has 3 columns. I want these columns to stack once the screen passes a certain width:

```
 <form id="shiftform" class="col s12 m12 l12">
      <div class="form-group col s0 m4 l4">
           {!! Form::label('shift_description',  trans('crud.shiftdescription'))!!}
           {!! Form::text('description', null, array('id'=> 'shift_description')) !!}
            {!!$errors->first('description', '<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col s0 m4 l4">
           {!! Form::label('shift_starttime', trans('crud.shiftstarttime'))!!}
           {!! Form::text('starttime', null, array('id'=> 'shift_starttime')) !!}
           {!!$errors->first('starttime', '<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col s0 m4 l4">
          {!! Form::label('shift_endtime', trans('crud.shiftendtime'))!!}
          {!! Form::text('endtime', null, array('id'=> 'shift_endtime')) !!}
          {!!$errors->first('endtime', '<span class=error>:message</span>')!!}
    </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0">
</form>
```

The form looks like this on every screen size:

(1)-----   (2)--------  (3)-------

Is there a way so it will become this

(1)------

(2)------

(3)------

when the screen becomes to small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup for the grid is incorrect. Use a row to include the columns. I don't think a class like s0 exists. Please read the docs: [Materialize Grid](http://materializecss.com/grid.html)

You can change your markup to:

```html
<div class="row">
  <form id="shiftform" class="col s12 m12 l12">
    <div class="form-group col m4 l4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col m4 l4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col m4 l4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="id" value="0" />
  </form>
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/q95f4xhc/)

Comment: Oh ok, you just drop the s value then :)  I also had to remove a fixed width setting from an enclosing div.

Comment: Joren, I didn't get it. You mean you can use this without adding row? :)

Comment: Okay, so what about when there are 5 items...? or really any number not divisible by 12

Comment: @DavidKnag Make use of `push` and `pull` classes. Did you check out this page? http://materializecss.com/grid.html If there are 5 items, use `pull-s7`.